# why using NULL with logical operator throws error in JS

Tags: javascript, null, logical-operators

This is the code I am testing --

Works fine

```
document.write( 1 && undefined ); // prints undefined
document.write( 1 && 3 ); // prints 3 
document.write( 1 && true ); // prints  true
```

Throws error

```
document.write( 1 && NULL ); // throws Error
```

why using NULL throws arror although its working even for undefined

although i tested typeof `NULL` and its giving `undefined` but still its not working.let me know about this. (New to OOP programming)

Comment: @Trailcoder can u try document.write( 1 && null );

Comment: Add this to make it work: `var NULL = null;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NULL` does not exist, try this

```
try {
    document.write( 1 &&  NULL  );
} catch ( e) {
    document.write( 1 &&  null  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is undefined because it doesn't exist. You're thinking of `null`.

Answer (score 1):

`document.write(1 && null);` outputs `null`.

`NULL` does not exist in JavaScript because it's case-sensitive. It must be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It's `null` (lowercase), not `NULL` (uppercase)

Answer (score 0):

Because `undefined` is different to a symbol that doesn't exist, the browser is throwing an error. From the Chrome console:

```
> 1 && null
null
> 1 && NULL
ReferenceError: NULL is not defined
> NULL
ReferenceError: NULL is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

read this may be it will answer your question
[JavaScript undefined vs. null](http://saladwithsteve.com/2008/02/javascript-undefined-vs-null.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using `typeof something` only gives the type of that expression; it's `undefined` in this case and so using that symbol naturally gives an error. It's the same as:

```
typeof unknownvar
// "undefined"
unknownvar
// ReferenceError: unknownvar is not defined
```

The exception is the symbol `undefined` itself:

```
typeof undefined
// "undefined"
undefined
// undefined
```

In your particular case, `NULL` should be `null`.