# How do I only add the field in an object if the value isn't null? Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently using mongoose to write data to a document in a MongoDB collection but I accept no null fields, I already have set default values in the document.
I call an update function that has some fields as null, those fields that are null already, I do not want them to make a modification.

Example:

```
const Business = require("./businessModel") //This references the model
const {id, email, name, contactNumber} = args
const business = await Business.findByIdAndUpdate(
  { id},
  {
   name: ((name != null) ? name : (skip this field))... //HERE
  });
```

Where I commented here, if the name is not null, which means a value exists for it then have the predefined schema value name now set to the new name input, otherwise don't change anything and just skip the field.
I do already have an alternative where I call the document first then replace it with the default value for the document but that requires a document call which I do not believe to be an optimal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `args` variable is an object with the relevant fields.

Instead of destructuring all the individual properties, you can extract just the `id` and leave the [`...rest`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread/blob/master/Rest.md). You can then filter this `rest` object for null properties.

```js
// mock
const args = { id: 1, name: null, email: 'email@domain', contactNumber: 4 };

//const Business = require("./businessModel") //This references the model

const { id, ...rest } = args;
const update = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(rest).filter(([, v]) => v != null));
console.log(update);

//const business = await Business.findByIdAndUpdate({id}, update);
```

More options for object property filtering here: [Remove blank attributes from an Object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38340730/13762301)

*Note: `NULL` doesn't exist, the null object in javascript is lowercase `null`. see: [why using NULL with logical operator throws error in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564584/why-using-null-with-logical-operator-throws-error-in-js)*

Comment: I have edited and corrected the null. Your solution is perfect and much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [update-validators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators). So in your case, check if value in `name` field `=== null`, and handle the error response as required.